# Find the volume for a solid of revolution using the shell method.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bound by $y = x^2$ and $y^2 = x$ about the line $y = -1$.

The shell method is preferred but the disks/washers method would also be helpful.

Comment: What have you gotten setup so far?

Comment: I have: $$\int_0^1 2pi(y+1)(y^{2} - {\sqrt\ y}) dy$$ But this seems to yield a negative volume so I'm very thrown off.

Comment: You have it correct except for the last parentheses. It should be $(\sqrt{y}-y^2)$ since the function $x=y^2$ is on the left and is therefore the smaller function.

Comment: From 0 to 1 bounds isn't $y^{2} = x$ the larger function?

Comment: Nope. Sketch the picture. When you are working with $y$ as the independent variable and $x$ as the dependent variable, smaller function values are farther left (towards $-\infty$ along the $x$-axis) and bigger function values are farther right (toward $\infty$ along the $x$-axis). You could also just evaluate $0.5^2 = 0.25$ while $\sqrt{0.5} \approx 0.707$.

Comment: Oops you are right! Thanks for the feedback, I think I have it now.

Comment: You can post your solution as the answer to this question. You'll have to wait a day (I think) before you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curves intersect at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.  For $0 \leq x \leq 1, \sqrt{x} \geq x^2.$

For the shell method, we add up cylindrical shell volumes: $dy\cdot 2\pi r h$.  So

$$V = 2 \pi \int_0^1 dy (1 + y)(\sqrt{y} - y^2).$$

For the washer method, we add up washer volumes:  $dx \cdot \pi (r_{out}^2 - r_{in}^2)$.  So:

$$V = \pi \int_0^1 dx [(1 + \sqrt{x})^2 - (1 + x^2)^2].$$

For both I get

$$V = \frac{29 \pi}{30}.$$